# Where to find the Deathclaw Gauntlet in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Where are the possible locations of finding this weapon, other than looting it from enemies or completing quests. There was the quest Devil's Due, but I chose alternative path, which is deliver the egg and so I couldn't get the weapon.

Comment: I believe the wiki says it is a random drop from deathclaws but I've never seen it happen myself.

Answer (score 12):

The currently known ways to get the Deathclaw Gauntlet are :

- Killing a deathclaw has some chance of dropping the deathclaw gauntlet and weapon merchants can sell them; they can start being stocked at Level 20.
- Occasionally used in combat by human enemies and can be looted upon their defeat. The chance for an enemy to spawn with this weapon appears to be very low.
- Can be found in front of the deathclaw nest during the quest The Devil's Due when returning the egg to its nest, northwest of Lynn Woods. It will be directly in front of the nest as the player character stare at the deathclaw guard. After approaching the nest with the egg from The Devil's Due, leaving the area without returning the egg will turn the deathclaw at the nest hostile. (I know you already said you tried this, but looking at your question it can be relevant for others)
- Can also be found just outside Atom Cats garage northeast side by the drainage outlets that spawn ghouls.
- Can be sold by vendors. Some say by Atom Cats vendors, some say diamond city or goodneighbor [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72881332?page=1)

[Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_gauntlet_(Fallout_4))

Comment: I've heard about the one at Atom Cats garage, but I just can't find the drainage outlet that spawn the ghouls. Or maybe I'm just not paying attention. I'll need directions.

Comment: I've been trying to get directions for you, but they are nowhere to be found. I do not have the possibility of checking it out myself yet. Might take a while, but if I do I will get you directions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible location is west of the reck of fms North Star where the water looks like a U inside a dolphin. There are weak enemies but quick save befor though becauss u have a better chance of getting a bat